# Can't get CSS Transitions to work with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, css-transitions

So I'm trying to build a web app that has div with a table on the left half of the screen, and a div full of textboxes and stuff for editing objects from the table on the right. On mobile, however, I'm trying to make both divs span 100% of the screen, with the left div appearing first, and if an object in its table is clicked, the div on the right slides over top of it.

Currently, I'm using absolute positioning to get the pages to look right, and I just set the right div's left equal to 100% of the page, and then turn its display to none. And when an object inside left div is clicked, it turns the display of right div to block and sets the left to 0. I've included CSS3 Transitions to try to get this to give a sliding effect. I also have to do all of this in ASP.NET code-behind, since that's what the project is in. So instead of using JQuery to toggle classes, I have to use C# to do it. I don't know if that's causing the problem, and if there's anything I can do about it.

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<div class="section admin_body">
    <div class="container left">
        [[table and other stuff here]]
    </div>
    <div class="container right" id="RightContainer" runat="server">
        [[other stuff here]]
    </div>
</div>
```

And some CSS:

```
.section.admin_body {
    margin: 1rem 0;
    position: relative;
    background: none;
    border: none;
}

.container.left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 99%;
    border: .1em solid #aaa;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    z-index: 1;
}

.container.right {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    width: 99%;
    border: .1em solid #aaa;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 3px;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transition: left 2s linear;
    -moz-transition: left 2s linear;
    -o-transition: left 2s linear;
    transition: left 2s linear;
}

.container.right.selected {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
}
```

And finally, the C#:

```
protected internal void LoadCase(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    BindData();
    LoadHeader();
    RightContainer.Attributes.Add("class", "container right selected");
}
```

I've got everything to work except the CSS transitions part. There's no sliding effect at all. Again, I'm not sure if it's because I'm using C# to Bind Data before I try to mess with the classes that activate the transitions. If anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong, I'd really appreciate the help!

Comment: Where's the source markup for `RightContainer`? You're showing the output HTML...

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have the Html elements in an UpdatePanel, setting the CSS via code behind like that will not work. The CSS class will be in the browser right from the start, so you wont see any animations transitioning from 1 style to another.

You might be able to achieve this effect by using an UpdatePanel or other Ajax method, are you not able to write any javascript on the WebForm at all?

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I tried wrapping it in an UpdatePanel though, and the page still loads and the transitions don't happen. Also, I do have javascript on the WebForm, just not for toggling classes since it only affects the current state of the page, and then gets erased once the page reloads.

Answer (score 0):

transitions, by my understanding, react to client side mouse actions

try this to see if there is an effect:

```
.container.right {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    width: 99%;
    border: .1em solid #aaa;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 3px;
    z-index: 99;
}

.container.right:hover {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: left 2s linear;
    -moz-transition: left 2s linear;
    -o-transition: left 2s linear;
    transition: left 2s linear;
}
```

Comment: Transitions work when the styles on the element change, that could be a mouse action or client side script changing the styles or classes on an element. In this case, the OP wants to add a class to an element when a certain condition happens.

Comment: right - but you have to prevent a postback to see the transition, unless the intent is to view the transition after a postback, in which case you'd need some JS to act on the elements.

Comment: Correct, or at least hide the postback within an UpdatePanel so as to allow the transition to occur. Also, a hover event wouldn't even work, seeing as the display is set to none.

Comment: the hover event was just a test case to see if transitions were working.  However I'm not sure if there is a hover event on mobile devices.  in any case, even with an update panel you still have a postback, but only the contents of the update panel are redrawn.  C# acts server side, JS/JQuery client side.  At best you would have to use C# to write JS to the page to perform slide effect you want, which seems overkill to me.  Couldn't you just use jquery's slideToggle() to trigger the right side elements based on a left side click?

Comment: I mean, essentially all that needs to happen is I need to change the left property of .container.right from 100% to 0 with the transitions allowing it to slide instead of just appear on top. I've tried things like using JQuery and C# to change the left attribute to 0, but it either doesn't work or doesn't trigger the transition, and I'm not really sure what I'm missing.